# My c++filt doesn't seem to work properly, no output changes

Tags: c++, linux, function, compilation, c++filt

On my linux, I've a .cpp file having

```
void f(){}
struct C{void f(){}};
```

I compiled it and strings the binary, try to de-mangle the function name:

```
$c++filt __Z1gv
__Z1gv
$c++filt __ZN1C1fEv
__ZN1C1fEv
```

Well, it doesn't seem to work as I expected. Did I get anything wrong here? Do I have to add some letters or remove some letters to make it work?

Note these names are clang symbols, seems c++filt only work for my gcc version? Or c++filt should have newer version to support both compilers?

Comment: How do you get the mangled names?

Comment: Use `nm` not `strings`. `nm -C` prints symbols already demangled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to pass the `-_` flag.

```
$ c++filt -_ __Z1gv
g()
$ c++filt -_ __ZN1C1fEv
C::f()
```

> **-_**
>   **--strip-underscore**
>
> > On some systems, both the C and C++ compilers put an underscore in front of every name.  For example, the C name "`foo`" gets the low-level name "`_foo`".  This option removes the initial underscore. Whether `c++filt` removes the underscore by default is target dependent.